# Is there a way to run JavaScript before browser extensions started loading?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a (chrome) browser extension that does read text contents of the page and highlight part of them when its loading. The extension usually works well but for some pages, like a page that you need to click "read more" (e.g. quora.com) to show the text contents, otherwise, the extension cannot recognize the text content and thus does not work. So, I thought if is there a way to run JavaScript that does programmatically click the "read more" or such things before the extensions loading, so the extension should be able to handle them. So, (how) is that possible?

Comment: No general way. Instead, detect inserted HTML and parse them when found.

Comment: Like using proxy?

Comment: More like a MutationObserver - watch for DOM mutations and do what you need